# Error during qiime1 installation on MacOS Mojave

Tags: qiime

I am trying to install qiime1 environment using terminal on Mac. Currently getting an error saying packages not found for matplotlib 1.4.3.

Comment: Please add more information in order to other users can give you a trusted anwser, form example, version of qiime1 that are you trying to install, version of MacOs, a print of the error that you are having.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same issue, matplotlib 1.4.3 package not found, and subsequently tried many different solutions, pip install and so on. So I am posting the solution that worked for me, I cannot remember where I found the different suggestions, but the downgrade of conda was key to make it work (thanks to whomever it was that suggested it in the first place):

```
conda config --set allow_conda_downgrades true
conda install conda=4.6.14
conda create -n qiime1 python=2.7 qiime matplotlib=1.4.3 mock nose -c bioconda
print_qiime_config.py -t
```

Once you've installed qiime you can upgrade your conda to the most recent version if you like